# Android - Using a method from a Library

Tags: android, android-library

I have setup my own android library and now want to use the methods within..

For some reason I am having issues understanding how this works, looking at other questions/ internet has not helped.

In my **library class** i have the following.

```
    public void testMethod(){

    Toast s = Toast.makeText(this, "test!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I want to be able to reference this in my main for example, how do i do this?

I have found several links which do look at this however it has not helped as it is different to what I want to do. Am I being very stupid and missing something?

I am guessing an interface needs to be setup on my **Main Class**? I am not sure.

**By the way I have already setup the library and have referenced in manifest etc..**

Comment: Does it not work if you make an object of the class in which the method exists and then you call object_name.testMethod();

Comment: sorry im a noobie when it comes to this... So creating an instance of the class as a object then referencing that?

Comment: Your class should  be public..Ensure you have imported the package.

Comment: @Ranjith yes I have done that.. just wasnt sure exactly how to reference as I have many many methods to implement (because it is a library)

Comment: Sidenote: You aren't calling .show() on the toast, so it isn't going to display anything even if you do succeed in calling the method

Comment: @RaghavSood yeah just noticed too, ill edit now but i dont care about the content just want to know how to reference a library method in my main or any other class.

Comment: Just like any other method. Create an instance of the class and then call it. Or in case of a static method, simply call it. This is basic Java, not Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import to your project the package name you used to create your library, then, create an object of the class you want to use from your library, and finally, call the method.

Supose your library package name it's:  "com.mylibrary"
Your library class it's called: "MyClass"
Your method it's called: "MyMethod"

In Your Project you should do:

```
//Import Your Library Package
import com.mylibrary;

//Instantiate The Library Class
MyClass mytest = new MyClass();

//Call The Library Class Method You Want To Use.
mytest.MyMethod();
```

Comment: just tried this, //Call The Library Class Method You Want To Use.
mytest.MyMethod(); doesnt work, says cannot resolve symbol?

Comment: Did you check that your project has reference to your library, if you're using eclipse, right click on your project and select properties, go to Android, at the botton of the android platforms you'll see a box where you can reference libraries, add your own there and apply.

Comment: I am using android studio and have made sure of this several times... I followed [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TForBjArUNg)

Comment: Ok, then, can you post an image showing the "Cannot Resolve Symbol" and the part where you call the method? and also, you can check the tips given by the IDE when there is an error or a warning, commonly they gives you options to fix them.

Comment: Ok, great, enjoy your development and have fun.

Comment: One more question, if I use another method which needs a context.. if I have used this to represent, and I am calling the method from my main would 'this' reference the library i have setup or my main?

Comment: Remember that context is relative to the class, so, using a context created by a class on another class, may throw you exceptions or give you errors, so, on your library, instead of using "this", receive a context as a parameter on your method, or make a Context object on your class and receive a context on your class constructor, this way, you may use the received context on any method inside your library class.

Comment: perfect it is what i had in mind but wasnt too sure if i was making sense, cheers :)

Comment: hmmm constructor doesnt seem to work... i cant pass anything to the library class? any other way?

plus for some reason its not allowing me to create a constructor on the library class?

Comment: Can you post your constructor code and how you're using it?

Comment: Hi i have now decided to move it to a service and it works there, thanks for your response anyway :)